# How to create button widget like facebook / twitter

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I wondering how to create crossdomain javascript functions to render button widget like facebook / twitter / google+ .

Any Ideas how to create that button?

Comment: Have you looked at facebook and google did?

Comment: @oknoorap This is a comprehensive explanation. http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

Answer (score 2):

Put everything in an iframe that you can place in any website. This is how Facebook does it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an iFrame. I'm pretty sure this is how Facebook does it.

Comment: Its crossbrowser or not? and how about the ajax stuff after button submit? its seem not crossbrowser (IE is bad)

Comment: If you are in an iFrame then the crossbrowser aspect doesn't matter. Oh, you mean crossbrowser as in will it work on all browsers? Of course an iFrame will. You really think Facebook would say "screw you" to all of it's IE customers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but still a good read on the subject:

http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/11/21/diy-widgets/